# How to interrupt triggered gitlab pipelines

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using a webhook to trigger my Gitlab pipeline. Sometimes, this trigger is triggered a bunch of times, but my pipelines only has to run the last one (static site generation). Right now, it will run as many pipelines as I have triggered. My pipelines takes 20 minutes so sometimes it's running the rest of the day, which is completely unnecessary.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#interruptible and https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/settings.html#auto-cancel-pending-pipelines only work on pushed commits, not on triggers

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm in the exact same situation.

Comment: No i did not sadly. I tried finding something many times.

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem is discussed in [`gitlab-org/gitlab-foss` issue 41560](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/41560)

Example of a use-case:

> I want to always push the same Docker "image:tag", for example: "myapp:dev-CI". The idea is that "myapp:dev-CI" should always be the latest Docker image of the application that matches the HEAD of the develop branch.
>   However if 2 commits are pushed, then 2 pipelines are triggered and executed in paralell. Then the latest triggered pipeline often finishes before the oldest one.
>   As a consequence the pushed Docker image is not the latest one.

[Proposition](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/41560#note_98811340):

> As a workaround for *nix you can get running pipelines from API and wait until they finished or cancel them with the same API.
>   In the example below script checks for running pipelines with lower id's for the same branch and sleeps.
>   jq package is required for this code to work.

[Or](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/41560#note_104540980):

> - Create a new runner instance
> - Configure it to run jobs marked as deploy with `concurrency 1`
> - Add the deploy tag to your CD job.
>
> It's now impossible for two deploy jobs to run concurrently.
>
> To guard against a situation where an older pipeline may run after a new one, add a check in your deploy job to exit if the current pipeline ID is less than the current deployment.

[Slight modification](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/41560#note_159978672):

> For me, one slight change: I kept the global `concurrency` setting the same (8 runners on my machine so concurrency: 8).
>   But, I tagged one of the runners with `deploy` and added `limit: 1` to its config.
>   I then updated my `.gitlab-ci.yml` to use the `deploy` tag in my `deploy` job.
>   Works perfectly: my `code_tests` job can run simultaneously on 7 runners but `deploy` is "single threaded" and any other `deploy` jobs go into pending state until that runner is freed up.

Comment: My problem isn't concurrency. Actually my pipelines are already running one by one. But my problem is with having 10 triggered pipelines in the queue, while all of them are redundant prettty soon. I only need the last one to run.

Comment: @LaurensKling The idea behind my answer is to avoid the creation of the nine other pipelines, that way, you don't have to manage the queue.

Comment: I found https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#resource_group, which can make sure you never run a job concurrent. But for me, extra pipelines are redundant, I'm using a static site generator. It will result into the same 10 times. I don't need the pipelines in between. But maybe you are suggesting I take the approach to ask the API if something is running? Seems like difficult code for me to manage. I'd rather use a feature.

Comment: @LaurensKling Are you using, as a static generator, Hugo? (https://gohugo.io/)

Comment: No I am using Gatsby